# Calculate desired profit given unit price and fee

Tags: arithmetic

This seems simple, but I'm struggling to find the answer...

How much should I sell my apple for if I want to achieve the desired profit?

- Cost for me to buy the apple (A) = £10
- Desired profit (B) = £3
- Final customer price fee (C) = 10%

Comment: what is final customer price fee?

Comment: What does "customer price fee" mean? What must be paid to whoever sells the puter?

Comment: The fee I have to pay to sell the item. This fee is based on the amount the customer pays for the item. In this example it is 10%. This eats into the potential profit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x = $ selling price.

$$10 + 3 + 0.10 \times x = x \iff 0.9 x = 13 \iff x = \dfrac {13}{0.9} \approx £\, 14.44$$

Comment: So how do I find x without knowing what it is?

Comment: See above: You have one variable, which appears in an equation: one equation, one unknown. Gather all terms with $x$ to one side, all constants remain on one side: $$10 + 3 + 0.10 \times x = 1\cdot x \iff 10 + 3 + 0.10 x - 0.10 x = 1\cdot x - 0.10 x \iff (1-0.1) x = 13 \iff 0.9 x = 13 \cdots$$

Comment: This's the first time I see the symbol £ on my keyboard. I never used it before;-)+1

Comment: @amWhy: Short and sweet +1